# Add progress towards goal to Comment Evaluator 5000

Tags: feature-request, comment-evaluator-5000

We were told in the invitation email that we should aim to spend approximately an hour with the Comment Evaluator 5000, or else our data might be completely trashed.  But how do I know how much time I've spent?  More importantly, presumably it's the amount of data, not the time spent ranking it, so am I faster than the expected rate?  Or slower?  I really just want to know how close I am to having hit the threshold that I need to hit for my time to not be wasted.

Comment: Also, if I do an hour an 30 minutes worth of rating, does that last 30 minutes not get counted?

Comment: "we should aim to spend approximately an hour" sounds like an excellent reason to find a better use of your time.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Possible to get some Stack Overflow Comment Evaluator 5000™ save points or signposts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314796/294055)

Comment: Then one can wonder why such a program that is considered spending time and energy on by the SE.com team ... has valid questions like this sitting around unanswered.